# Remove left padding in SwiftUI NavigationView with Form and Picker

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I'm new to Swift and trying to add a photo picker to a NavigationView. It seems to work fine except for I can't seem to get rid of the left padding around the Image and get it centered. I have read that using a List instead of Form with ".listStyle(GroupedListStyle())" fixes the issue, but that only fixes it for the padding of the picker and not for the second view with the Image. At this point I've tried many things to no avail and would appreciate some pointers.

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Picker("Backgrounds", selection: $currentBackground) {
                    TabView  {
                                // Image goes here
                                Image(..) 
                            }

                        }
                        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
                        .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height * 0.9, alignment: .center)
                        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)

                        .border(.blue, width: 1)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Settings", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: cancel, trailing: done)
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This might be because of `GeometryReader`. I see that you're not using it other than for size, so try `UIScreen.main.bounds.height` or `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` for size. Remove the `GeometryReader` - that might fix the issue.

Comment: @Mr Developer Thank you for your suggestion! Removing GeometryReader didn't solve it unfortunately, but I've learned how to set width and height without it :) I think the issue is the Form / Picker. If I remove them and just keep the Image inside my NavigationView the padding goes away. I don't know if it's possible to tweak the Form to get rid of it.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. A question - do you have a `NavigationView` in that second part where the image is? If so, your alignment might be off because of that. If the image is always moved the same direction and amount every time, you could try the `.offset` modifier, and use the same `UIScreen` method to have it scale for the screen.

Comment: I only have one NavigationView as shown in the code above. Using .offset can fix the issue for one type of device, but it looks very different on another. I tried fixed offset and also relative adjustment, but it had a very different look on the iPad vs iPhone.